# how to prevent child component from reload when the parent state is change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a scenario in which the parent component send the `imgkey` `props` to the child component . When child component load that image, it can change `img` and  return back to the parent by changing it's state through callback.

Now parent component have other features and when the other features make the state change then the child component (image) is load every time .how can i prevent to reload on the same `imgkey` props ?

**overall when the parent send the same prop `imgkey` as it send previously then child should not reload**

Comment: you want [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: @Hamms but that will be for whole parent component not for child

Comment: specifically, define `shouldComponentUpdate` for the child

Comment: I might be missing something here, but it might be possible to resolve this simply by making your child component extend from `PureComponent` rather than `Component` (more on PureComponent [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)). As long as you're avoiding direct mutations of objects in your state and props (which you should do anyhow), `PureComponent`  usually will prevent unnecessary re-renders without any negative side-effects.

Comment: Just re-read the question and realized that the parent component might need to be a `PureComponent` as well, or if that doesn't work then you'll need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` manually as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it depends on your child component, if the child needs to:

- Keep render or follow-up some logic; or
- It is dispensable and we can skip rendering it

### Child

This component will keep rendering and sometime only run some logic if needed.

```
class Child extends Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.id % 10 === 0) {
      return { shouldRunLogic: true };
    }
    return { shouldRunLogic: false };
  }
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { shouldRunLogic: false };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Let's do our stuff once DOM mounted
    this.handleSomeLogic();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Do we need to call our logic again?
    if (this.state.shouldRunLogic) {
      this.handleSomeLogic();
    }
  }
  handleSomeLogic() {
    // do some stuff
    this.props.onFinish('Child finished the logic');
  }
  render() {
    // Makes sure we always render for children if any
    return <div>{this.props.id}-{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

---

### DispensableChild

This component just does one thing and never re-render after the logic is finished.

```
class DispensableChild extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { isComplete: false };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Let's do our stuff once DOM mounted
    this.handleSomeLogic();
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !this.state.isComplete;
  }
  handleSomeLogic() {
    // do some stuff
    // ...
    // Let's make sure this component never render again
    this.setState({ isComplete: true }, () => this.props.onFinish('DispensableChild finished the logic'));
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.isComplete || <div>Doing some logic</div>;
  }
}
```

---

### Parent

Includes both child components but only Child will continue to render.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { childId: 1 };
    this.handleFinish = this.handleFinish.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // Let's pass the prop every 15 secs
    setInterval(() =>
      this.setState(({ childId }) => ({ childId: childId + 1})), 15000);
  }
  handleFinish(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child id={this.state.childId} onFinish={this.handleFinish} />
        <DispensableChild id={this.state.childId} onFinish={this.handleFinish} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```